# struct in a different assembly used without initialization

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

The following C# program doesn't compile

```
    class Program
    {
        public struct MetaWorkspace
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Id { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MetaWorkspace ws;
            ws.Id = "abc";
        }
    }
```

The compiler complains: `error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'ws`'

The compiler is Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.10.0-4.21329.37 and the version of .NET Framework is 4.7.2

But, the same program compiles successfully when the `MetaWorkspace` struct definition is moved into a different assembly (DLL) and is included as a reference. How is this so? If this is not an error, am I still dealing with a fully defined `MetaWorkspace` object or have I tread into the undefined zone?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I have tried this exercise repeatedly in Visual Studio 2019 Ver 16.10.4. Each time I observe the same behavior

Comment: Code also runs just fine. The variable contains an empty struct, even though it's never created

Comment: @Dominik Hopefully, there's no undefined behavior going on under the hood waiting to explode at a later time!

Comment: OK so when the struct is defined in another assembly I get a warning `Warning CS8887 Use of unassigned local variable 'ws'` and if it's defined in the same assembly I get an error `Error CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'ws'`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Is the warning benign? It's not showing up in my environment. Which version of compiler and .NET framework are you using?

Comment: That's using .net 5.0 with Visual Studio 16.11.2. The warning must be benign for a value type, since `ws` itself it can't be null, although its contents will be initialised with all zeros or null references, so if you did `ws.Id.Length` without initialising, it would crash with a NullReferenceException.

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: Note: If you make it a class instead of a struct, you *do* get a compile error.

Comment: I just checked the IL output and it's identical whether you declare `ws` as `MetaWorkspace ws;` or as `MetaWorkspace ws = new MetaWorkspace();`, so it's definitely benign, albeit wrong.

Comment: @MatthewWatson In .NET 4.7.2, I am observing there's a difference. The IL generated when `ws` is initialized has the following lines added:`IL_0003:  initobj    [ClassLibrary1]ClassLibrary1.MetaWorkspace
  IL_0009:  ldloca.s   ws
` I guess that extra code is initializing the variable `ws`

Comment: @MatthewWatson I just checked now. Those two extra lines of IL code are present in the release build, too.

Comment: I still think it's benign - it seems like later versions of the compiler are omitting the unnecessary re-initialisation (since the struct will always be filled with zeros when it is created by the CLR). The discrepancy with warnings is definitely not right, however!

Comment: Hope so. I added the constructor call just to be on the safe side. The only thing that disturbs me is that the behavior not documented anywhere. Hence, there's no safety assurance on the harmlessness of the missing error diagnostic in .NET 4.7.2 or the harmlessness of the missing call to initobj in IL code.

Comment: Might be worth posting about this in https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues

Comment: @MatthewWatson https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/5230